# Error starting roo shell in osx 10.6.8 with java 7

Tags: macos, shell, java-7, spring-roo

I am using mac 10.6.8 (snow leopard). I replaced the original JDK 6 installation with JDK 7 (which, incidentally, cannot be done in a completely clean way in my OS) so now the "java" command points to the jre in 7 and JAVA_HOME is set to the 7 installation too. I then installed maven 3.0.5 and finally spring roo through homebrew. When I try starting the roo shell I get the error message below. I have no clue as to the nature of the problem.

Is there any way to pass a parameter to roo to use a difference jre, for example?

> $ roo
>   Nov 12, 2013 10:38:53 PM org.springframework.roo.felix.JdkDelegatingLogListener logNow
>   SEVERE: [org.springframework.roo.uaa [71]] [org.springframework.roo.uaa.UaaRelatedComponentRegistrationHelper] The activate method has thrown an exception
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libosx.dylib: dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libosx.dylib, 1): Symbol not found: _JNFRunLoopDidStartNotification
>     Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/./libosxapp.dylib
>     Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/JavaNativeFoundation
>    in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/./libosxapp.dylib
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
>       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
>       at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
>       at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.util.prefs.MacOSXPreferencesFile.(MacOSXPreferencesFile.java:82)
>       at java.util.prefs.MacOSXPreferences.cfFileForNode(MacOSXPreferences.java:137)
>       at java.util.prefs.MacOSXPreferences.(MacOSXPreferences.java:103)
>       at java.util.prefs.MacOSXPreferences.(MacOSXPreferences.java:77)
>       at java.util.prefs.MacOSXPreferences.getUserRoot(MacOSXPreferences.java:58)
>       at java.util.prefs.MacOSXPreferencesFactory.userRoot(MacOSXPreferencesFactory.java:30)
>       at java.util.prefs.Preferences.userRoot(Preferences.java:457)
>       at java.util.prefs.Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Preferences.java:371)
>       at org.springframework.uaa.client.util.PreferencesUtils.getPreferencesFor(PreferencesUtils.java:34)
>       at org.springframework.uaa.client.internal.UaaServiceImpl.(UaaServiceImpl.java:71)
>       at org.springframework.uaa.client.UaaServiceFactory.getUaaService(UaaServiceFactory.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.uaa.client.UaaServiceFactory.getUaaService(UaaServiceFactory.java:42)
>       at org.springframework.roo.uaa.UaaRelatedComponentRegistrationHelper.activate(UaaRelatedComponentRegistrationHelper.java:28)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:227)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:38)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:591)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:472)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:146)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ImmediateComponentManager.createImplementationObject(ImmediateComponentManager.java:226)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ImmediateComponentManager.createComponent(ImmediateComponentManager.java:118)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$Unsatisfied.activate(AbstractComponentManager.java:997)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:333)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:157)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ConfiguredComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfiguredComponentHolder.java:256)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.loadDescriptor(BundleComponentActivator.java:253)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialize(BundleComponentActivator.java:147)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.(BundleComponentActivator.java:111)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:285)
>       at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.bundleChanged(Activator.java:203)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:807)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:729)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:610)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:3879)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1850)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Nov 12, 2013 10:38:53 PM org.springframework.roo.felix.JdkDelegatingLogListener logNow
SEVERE: [org.springframework.roo.uaa [71]] [org.springframework.roo.uaa.UaaRelatedComponentRegistrationHelper] Component instance could not be created, activation failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a real solution for JDK 7, so I finally simply pointed my JAVA_HOME variable to java 6 and it works now.

It must be some particularity of the interaction between the JDK 7 installation and OSX snow leopard that I could not understand.